# How can I use ngrx in resolver

Tags: angular, ngrx

How can I use the data which is stored in store in route resolver?

I have a route resolver and before it loads an Id from service and then it calls several API calls and adds them as observable with fork-join. But know I need to wait for the result of the store and then call these APIs.

Answer (score 0):

As much as this is possible to do by either creating a promise or an observable and resolve once you finished storing subscription in the store. You are following bad design practice.

```
return new Promise((res) => forkJoin(...).subscribe((result) => {
   this.store.dispatch(result);
   res(result);
}))
```

That's how you can do it. But you should look at using NGRX effects

Comment: How come the effects will solve the issue? for example, consider I have a customerId which is stored in store and I want to load it and then get all product types for that customer and then resolve the component. How can I do that with effects?

Comment: @rezord You should take a look at the example: https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b